# Returning part of a string from a text file

Tags: string, powershell

Working on a script that will enumerate over a few computers and check a known text file for a string: `Value=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX`.  The "X's" will be varying length as well as a mix of letters and numbers.  Would regex be over complicating it vs `-split` ?

Comment: More context is needed. Why would you consider a regex if the string always has fixed header?

Comment: It's a question, as I was unsure.  To further the context. The script will be polling a known set of computers, looking in a specific location for a file. In that file is the text blocked out above.  I need to return the XXXXX after Value=, no matter how long or what characters it contains.  Basically, find the string Value= and return what is after it.

Answer (score 0):

This returns what I was looking for:

```
$value = get-content c:\pathOfFile\file.txt | select-string "value="
("$value" -split '=')[1]
```